# Protect a Worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, protected

I am attempting to create a excel document for technicians to enter data into.

I want to make it so that when one technician enters in the information on line 7, that once he/she is finished, it automatically becomes protected so that the next technician or person can only change and edit line 8 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of Excel may be different, but Office 365 would do it like this:
[image]

1. Go to Review
2. Go to Protect>Allow Edit Ranges
3. Enter a password to protect those cells
4. Edit permissions - this is new to the newer versions of Excel.
5. Define the groups and locations that the permissions apply to.
6. Make them "Deny" permissions, disallowing the top 7 lines.
7. Hit Apply
8. Hit Yes.